# Getting unique relation records by eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two tables users and accounts:

```
 id     name    
------------- 
 1       joe
 2       jane
 3       phil
```

and accounts table :

```
id   user_id      account       account_number   is_active
----------------------------------------------------------
1      1           visa              11             1
2      1           visa              22             0
3      1           master            12             0
4      2           visa              33             0
6      3            visa             44             1
7      3            master           55             1
```

I want to get all users with their accounts. if the account is active we should have active one and if not one of the non active records. final collection would be something like this:

```
users = [
'joe'=>[
  'visa'=>1,
  'master'=>0
],

'jane'=>[
  'visa'=>0
 ],
'phil'=>[
  'visa'=>1,
  'master'=>1
]
```

thanks

Comment: Hi! Did you try any code? Could you publish your models, controllers...?

Comment: What have you tried so far, where did you get stuck?  Did you try checking the docs?  You need to [create 2 models](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent), and [relationships between them](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: ... and then something like `User:with('accounts')->get()` will generate that kind of result.  The docs use posts with comments as examples - that's quite similar to your users and accounts, so easy to use their examples as guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
$users = User::with('accounts')->get();
```

For this to work you need to have your relation User->accounts defined in your User model.

The relation would be one to many like so:

```php
public function accounts()
{
 $this->hasMany(Account::class)
}
```

If you need to consult more about relations check the Laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many